# Loopback cli (lb4) crashing on launch

Tags: command-line, loopback

After installing lb4 cli (npm i -g @loopback/cli), I'm unable to launch lb4 from the command line (Ubuntu 18.04). I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@loopback/cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
```

Thanks in advance for any help on how this could be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is that you are using Node.js version 8, which does not support optional `catch` binding (a part of ES2017, see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding).

LoopBack requires Node.js version 10 or newer to run. Please upgrade your Node.js version to 10.x or newer.